# Double integral of exponential

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, exponential-function

I would like to calculate an integral on the form
$$
\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty x^n y^me^{-ax^2-by^2-cxy}  \text{ d}x\text{d}y.
$$
Is there any way to approach this problem analytically? $a$ and $b$ are complex numbers with a real part equal to 1, and $c$ is real.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, if the matrix $$\begin{pmatrix} a & \frac{c}2\\ \frac{c}2 & b\end{pmatrix}$$ has eigenvalues with non-positive real part, the integral diverges. If $m, n$ are even then your integral is one quarter of the integral over the whole plane, and then you can diagonalize in the exponent, and your integral will have the form

$$C \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} (c_1 x + c_2y )^m (c_3 x + c_4 y)^n \exp(-x^2 + y^2) d x d y,$$ which will be a polynomial in $\Gamma$s and other Gaussian stuff.